# How to write the iota descriptor in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm exercising my proving skills with the book “Mereology” of Cotnoir and Varzi (2021). The first definitions given in the book, after accepting the primitive binary relation P, are :

```
(D1) PPxy := Pxy /\ ~ (x = y)
(D2) Oxy := ∃z (Pzx /\ Pzy)
(D3) Uxy := ∃z (Pxz /\ Pyz)
(D4) Dxy := ~∃z (Pzx /\ Pzy)
(D5) x - y := ιz∀w (Pwz <-> (Pwx /\ Dwy))
```

So, I coded the primite and the first four definitions like this:

```
Parameter Entity : Set.
Parameter P : Entity -> Entity -> Prop.

Definition PP x y := P x y /\ x <> y.
Definition O x y := exists z, P z x /\ P z y.
Definition U x y := exists z, P x z /\ P y z.
Definition D x y := ~ exists z, P z x /\ P z y.
```

However, I don’t know how to code the fifth one. I identified that it should be a function of type `Entity -> Entity -> Entity` as the iota operator (ι) refers to the one z that satisfies the following formula. Therefore, "x - y" should return the given z.

At it looks like an operator, I first tried with a notation:

```
Notation "x - y" := (exists z, forall w ,(P w z <-> (P w x /\ D w y))).
```

However, as I expected, this is not what I wanted. I checked the type of "x - y":

```
Variables x y: Entity.
Check x - y.
```

And I got, as expected, the type `Prop`, and not `Entity`.

After a search on Google, I find this in the standard library: [Library Coq.Logic.ClassicalDescription](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.ClassicalDescription.html), and in particular a definition of a iota operator, but I didn’t understand how to use it.

Therefore, I have two questions: is my implementation choices (in particular the `Parameter`s `Entity` and `P`) ok? and if so, how can I implement the operation "x - y"?

Answer (score 0):

There exists a short description of an example of use of the `iota`and `epsilon` operators in https://coq-community.org/hydra-battles/doc/hydras.pdf (starting p. 163).

For instance, the successor of any ordinal is defined by

```
Definition succ (alpha : Ord)
  := the_least (fun beta => alpha < beta).
```

where `the_least` is defined in terms of `iota`.

There are also a few definitions and simple lemmas in https://github.com/coq-community/hydra-battles/blob/master/theories/ordinals/Schutte/MoreEpsilonIota.v

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. But if you want to use the `iota` in the Classical Description, it may look like

```
Require Import ClassicalDescription.

Parameter Entity : Set.
Parameter P : Entity -> Entity -> Prop.

Definition PP x y := P x y /\ x <> y.
Definition O x y := exists z, P z x /\ P z y.
Definition U x y := exists z, P x z /\ P y z.
Definition D x y := ~ exists z, P z x /\ P z y.
Definition B x y := iota x (fun z => forall w , (P w z <-> (P w x /\ D w y))).
Notation "x - y" := (B x y).

Lemma B_spec x y w : P w (x - y) <-> (P w x /\ D w y).
Proof.
apply (iota_spec x (fun z => forall w , (P w z <-> (P w x /\ D w y)))).
```

Comment: By using x as the first argument of the iota function in the definition of B, it means that x - y = x?

Comment: The first argument of `iota` is just a guarantee that the type `A` is inhabited. 
For comparison's sake, the type of `iota` in `Epsilon.v` is ` forall [A : Type], inhabited A -> (A -> Prop) -> A`.

Comment: Thus, the value of this first argument doesn't really matter. It's just a proof that the type `A`is not empty, which would give a contradiction with the use of `iota`or `epsilon`to create terms of type `A`.